# add column in spark dataframe referring another dataframe using udf

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I've a dataframe "`Forecast`" with columns - `Store, Item, FC_startdate, FC_enddate, FC_qty`

Another dataframe "`Actual`" with columns - `Store, Item, Saledate, Sales_qty`.

I want to create a `UDF` with parameters passed - `p_store, p_item, p_startdate, p_enddate` and get the sum of `Sales_qty` in between these dates and add this as a new column (`Act_qty`) to "`Forecast`" dataframe.

but spark is not allowing to pass a dataframe in UDF along with fields of Forecast.

Instead of using merge - What can be the solution?

Comment: spark allow UDF with DataFrame, could you please provide sample data and also UDF that you have tried to use .

Answer (score 0):

After defining and registering your udf, you can use the udf function in your transformation code like any other function of the spark-sql library.

Similar to the spark-sql library functions you can only pass columns of your dataframe and return the processed value. **Dataframes cannot be passed to udf's.**

So in your case you can transform your current dataframe into another dataframe by using the udf as a function and then proceed ahead.
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html

Answer (score 0):

A golden rule is, that anything that can be done without `UDFs`, should be done without `UDFs`, they should be applied more-so when you require a very specific transformation on a singular row, rather than for the *big aggregation type* operation you decribe.

In this case it seems like you could just use SparkSQL: Select rows of `Actual`, where the `Saledate` is between the dates you would like (Spark understands dates natively, refer to the documentation), sum `SalesQty` per `Store` or `Item`, or both (I am not sure what you intend to do), rename the sum column and join this new dataframe into the `Forecast` using `Store` or `Item` or both again.

If you, however, insist on using `UDFs` you will have to pass columns, rather than dataframes as arguments but I can't think of a straightforward way of how to achieve what you describe using `UDFs` while not sacrificing a lot of performance.